Jupyter notebook not running in browser in WSL2
enter image description here
I am unable to get the token for launching jupyter notebook in browser. What should I do next?
Please let me know any auxiliary libraries that I have not yet downloaded. As you can see I have installed jupyter notebook in WSL but it is not outputting the token ip address.

Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as (properly formatted) text, not (just) as images.

I'm only speculating, but, going by the last log message in your screenshot, perhaps adding --allow-root to the invocation command line helps.
